# Consulta incluindo várias tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma tabela pessoas que tem as pessoas de `funcionarios`, `pais` e `maes`, eu já consegui relacionar todo mundo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que olha o jeito que retorna. eu preciso que as `maes` fiquem na primeira linha, igual está os `pais`.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT mae.nomepessoa as Mae,''as Pai FROM  dbo.bpm_pessoa mae 
 INNER JOIN dbo.bpm_pessoarelacionamento maerelacionamento on
  maerelacionamento.idpessoaprincipal = mae.idpessoa where maerelacionamento.idtiporelacionamentopessoa = 3 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT '' as pai,pai.nomepessoa as pai FROM dbo.bpm_pessoa AS  pai 
INNER JOIN dbo.bpm_pessoarelacionamento pairelacionamento on 
pairelacionamento.idpessoaprincipal = pai.idpessoa where pairelacionamento.idtiporelacionamentopessoa = 2
)
AS RESULTADO
```

Comment: Consegue postar uma estrutura resumida das suas tabelas e qual é o resultado esperado? Somente com as consultas não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: É o seguinte : a tabela (dbo.bpm_pessoa) tem os dados de várias pessoas.. Para saber exatamente quem é um 'funcionario ou pai do funcionario ou mae do funcionario' está relação está na tabela (dbo.bpm_pessoarelacionamento) onde 'idtiporelacionamentopessoa' diz o tipo de pessoas. Se for 2 entao a pessoa é 'Pai' se for 3 entao é 'Mae'.. Eu já consegui fazer as referencias.. só que está exibindo de forma incorreta.. eu quero que ambas as informações de 'pai e mae' seja exibida nas primeiras linhas..

Comment: E como se obtém somente as linhas de funcionários da tabela bpm_pessoa?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando dois `LEFT JOIN` consegue perfeitamente relacionar as 3 tabelas:

```
SELECT      bpm.nomepessoa              as pessoa
        ,   ISNULL(mae.nomepessoa, '')  AS mae
        ,   ISNULL(pai.nomepessoa, '')  AS pai
FROM        bpm_pessoa  bpm
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      ps.idpessoa
                        ,   ps.nomepessoa
                FROM        bpm_pessoa                  ps
                INNER JOIN  bpm_pessoarelacionamento    pr  ON  pr.idpessoaprincipal            = ps.idpessoa
                                                            AND pr.idtiporelacionamentopessoa   = 3
            )           mae ON mae.idpessoa = bpm.idpessoa
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      ps.idpessoa
                        ,   ps.nomepessoa
                FROM        bpm_pessoa                  ps
                INNER JOIN  bpm_pessoarelacionamento    pr  ON  pr.idpessoaprincipal            = ps.idpessoa
                                                            AND pr.idtiporelacionamentopessoa   = 2
            )           pai ON pai.idpessoa = bpm.idpessoa
```

Comment: o nome de pessoas vem da tabela 'bpm_pessoa' nesse caso vai dar erro, porque a tabela bpm_pessoarelacionamento só tem o 'id , que é a representacao do relacionamento' eu preciso mostrar os nomes de mae e pai.. entendeu ?

Comment: Tem toda a razão! Resposta editada!

Comment: quase certo, só que agora ele exibe a mesma informacao nas duas colunas , adicionei a imagem la em cima

Comment: @FabioHenrique Colega, essa edição está indevida. O ideal é você passar o link da imagem via comentário, ao invés de editar a resposta. ;)

Comment: Tem a certeza que a informação nas suas tabelas está correta? Consegue editar a sua questão e colocar mais informação sobre as suas tabelas?

Comment: Falta certamente algum campo de ligação entre a pessoa e a mãe/pai. Coloque a estrutura das suas tabelas na sua questão pf.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Resultado.mae,Resultado.Pai
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT 1 As Ordem,mae.nomepessoa as Mae,''as Pai
    FROM dbo.bpm_pessoa As mae 
    JOIN dbo.bpm_pessoarelacionamento As maerelacionamento
        ON maerelacionamento.idpessoaprincipal = mae.idpessoa
    WHERE maerelacionamento.idtiporelacionamentopessoa = 3 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT 2 As Ordem,'' as pai,pai.nomepessoa as pai
    FROM dbo.bpm_pessoa AS pai
    JOIN dbo.bpm_pessoarelacionamento As pairelacionamento
        ON pairelacionamento.idpessoaprincipal = pai.idpessoa
    WHERE pairelacionamento.idtiporelacionamentopessoa = 2
)
AS RESULTADO
ORDER BY Resultado.Ordem,Resultado.mae,Resultado.pai
```